# Sublime 4/Vintage: repeat key on key down only in edit mode

Tags: macos, vim, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublimetext4

On my mac, I need to be able to access special characters such as accents for editing purposes and for now I access this by holding a key down and then get the suggestions shortcut.

However, I would like to use the Vim mode in Sublime as well so moving around with h, j, k, l is quite tedious if I can't hold the key down to move faster.

Is there any way to only repeat a key when pressing it down in edit mode, or to have this behaviour only for h, j, k, l?

Thanks

Comment: FWIW, `hjkl` are terrible ways to move around, in Vim or in Vim emulators. There are much better ways. Much, much better ways. See `:help motion.txt` in real Vim.

Comment: Also depending on layout and language you are looking at, you can use modifiers. for example `\`` and `a` will result in a `à` for me.

Answer (score 2):

Probably unsurprisingly, the press-and-hold-for-special-characters behavior is a macOS feature. It doesn't seem possible to change the behavior on the fly. You can adjust it per app [like this](https://github.com/NeoVintageous/NeoVintageous/issues/816):

```bash
defaults write com.sublimetext.4 ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

So the question becomes: how can you enter special characters in insert mode? In vanilla vim, you could use `inoremap` to replace, say, <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> with "ł". However, [NeoVintageous](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/NeoVintageous) (which I hope you're using, not the deprecated [Vintage mode](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/vintage.html)) does not support remaps in insert mode. It [claims](https://github.com/NeoVintageous/NeoVintageous/blob/master/res/doc/quickref.txt) to support [digraphs](https://vimhelp.org/digraph.txt.html), which would be another way of achieving this. However, the keyboard command to insert a digraph is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>, which conflicts with one of the default Sublime Text key bindings on macOS. (The one to kill from the cursor to EOL, which is copied from Emacs and available in [standard macOS text fields](https://jblevins.org/log/kbd).) It's presumably possible to work around this, but I felt like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> was kind of wordy anyway.

Fortunately, there IS a fast, simple solution: a Sublime key remap. Open your user key bindings (Sublime Text > Preferences > Key Bindings) and add this one:

```json
    { "keys": ["option+l"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "ł"} }
```

Now <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> will add the l-slash character to your document. If you need the special character this is replacing (the [not sign](https://codepoints.net/U+00AC?lang=en) "¬"), you can of course choose another binding.

I presume this is the one you want, since it's the only special character available for me when I press-and-hold any of the hjkl keys. But this approach will work equally well for any other characters you might want to insert.